# How to access database from RecyclerView Adapter holder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I'm in need of advice on how to get data from the database, or whatever approach is best, from a RecyclerView adapter `onBindViewHolder()` method. Basically I have a list of `Transactions` that the ViewHolder cycles through, which contains an ID for a related entity called `Payee`, which I can obtain by accessing the `Transaction`'s `getPayeeByID` method. (That method already exists to pull the info in the repository and Dao and works fine.) The problem is, how do I access that method from this screen?  I need to know how get to it from here so I can create a new `Payee` based on the pulled `PayeeId`, in order to set the `holder.payee.setText` field with the name of the associated `Payee`. I have no idea how to do that from here.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Transaction transaction = tTransactions.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());


   holder.payee.setText( ????????? ) ;        
   holder.date.setText(date);
   holder.transAmount.setText(amount);
```

I am happy to add more code if needed.

Comment: please be more articulate about what you want to implement

Comment: @Levi I'm trying to access the database from the block of code above, to create a new Payee from the PayeeId associated with the Transaction. Do I need to access the repository? The ViewModel? If so, how do I do that from here, or is there another way to do that? Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the solution to this. I just created an instance of the repository  and accessed the DB through that. See below:

```
 AppRepository repository = new AppRepository(tContext);

 final Payee payee = repository.getPayeeById(transaction.getPayeeId());

 holder.payee.setText(payee.getName());
```